# antlr4 line 2:0 mismatched input 'if' expecting {'if', OTHER}

Tags: parsing, if-statement, antlr, lexer

I am having a bit of difficulty in my g4 file. Below is my grammar:

```
// Define a grammar called Hello
grammar GYOO;
program   : 'begin' block+ 'end';

block
    : statement+
    ;

statement 
    : assign
    | print 
    | add
    | ifstatement
    | OTHER {System.err.println("unknown char: " + $OTHER.text);}
    ;


assign    
    : 'let' ID 'be' expression 
    ;

print     
    : 'print' (NUMBER | ID) 
    ;


ifstatement
    : 'if' condition_block (ELSE IF condition_block)* (ELSE stat_block)?
    ;


add       
    : (NUMBER | ID) OPERATOR (NUMBER | ID) ASSIGN ID 
    ;

stat_block
    : OBRACE block CBRACE
    | statement
    ;

condition_block
    : expression stat_block
    ;
expression
    : NOT expression                                    //notExpr
    | expression (MULT | DIV | MOD) expression       //multiplicationExpr
    | expression (PLUS | MINUS) expression           //additiveExpr
    | expression (LTEQ | GTEQ | LT | GT) expression  //relationalExpr
    | expression (EQ | NEQ) expression               //equalityExpr
    | expression AND expression                         //andExpr
    | expression OR expression                          //orExpr
    | atom                                              //atomExpr  
    ;
atom
    : (NUMBER | FLOAT)  //numberAtom
    | (TRUE | FALSE) //booleanAtom
    | ID             //idAtom
    | STRING         //stringAtom
    | NULL           //nullAtom
    ;

ID     : [a-z]+ ;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
OPERATOR : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/';
ASSIGN : '=';
WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') + -> skip;
OPAR : '(';
CPAR : ')';
OBRACE : '{';
CBRACE : '}';
TRUE : 'true';
FALSE : 'false';
NULL : 'null';
IF : 'if';
ELSE : 'else';

OR : 'or';
AND : 'and';
EQ : 'is';              //'=='
NEQ : 'is not';         //'!='
GT : 'greater';         //'>'
LT : 'lower';           //'<'
GTEQ : 'is greater';    //'>=' 
LTEQ : 'is lower';      //'<='

PLUS : '+';
MINUS : '-';
MULT : '*';
DIV : '/';
MOD : '%';
POW : '^';
NOT : 'not';

FLOAT
 : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]* 
 | '.' [0-9]+
 ;

STRING
 : '"' (~["\r\n] | '""')* '"'
 ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
OTHER
 : . 
 ;
```

When i try to -gui tree from antlr it shows me this error:

```
line 2:3 missing OPERATOR at 'a'
```

This error is given from this code example:

```
begin
let a be true
if a is true
print a
end
```

Basically it does not recognizes the ifstatement beggining with IF 'if' and it shows the tree like i am making an assignment.

[image: tree]

How can i fix this?

P.S. I also tried to reposition my statements. Also tried to remove all statements and leave only ifstatement, and same thing happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is at least one issue:

```
ID     : [a-z]+ ;

...

TRUE : 'true';
FALSE : 'false';
NULL : 'null';
IF : 'if';
ELSE : 'else';
OR : 'or';

...

NOT : 'not';
```

Since `ID` is placed before `TRUE` .. `NOT`, those tokens will never be created since `ID` has precedence over them (and `ID` matches these tokens as well).

Start by moving `ID` beneath the `NOT` token.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, at least right now it is working and not throwing errors. i will correct the other parts too. But my error is gone :).